# request for member ' ' in something not a structure or union error hashTable separate chaining

Tags: c, struct, hashtable

The following code gives me the following errors :

```
error: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union
error: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union
error: request for member ‘data’ in something not a structure or union
error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
```

How could I fix it ?
Code is :

```
#define SIZE 5

typedef struct hashTable{
    int data;
    char *name;
    struct hashTable *next;
} table;


int hash_function(int value)
{
    return value % SIZE;
}

int insert(char *inFileName, table ***hashLinked)
{
    FILE *inFile;
    int val = -1;
    char str[30];
    int probe;

    if ((inFile = fopen(inFileName, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening input file, %s\n", inFileName);
        return -1;
    }
    while(fscanf(inFile,"%s %d",str,&val) == 2)
    {
        probe = hash_function(val);

        if(hashLinked[probe] == NULL)
        {                             
            **hashLinked[probe] = malloc(sizeof(table));   
            **hashLinked[probe]->name = (char *)malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char*));
            strcpy(**hashLinked[probe]->name,str);

            **hashLinked[probe]->data = val;
            **hashLinked[probe]->next = NULL;
        }                                             
        else
        {   
            table* hashLinkedNode = *hashLinked[probe];
            while(hashLinkedNode->next!=NULL)
            {                           
                hashLinkedNode = hashLinkedNode->next;
            }
            hashLinkedNode->next = malloc(sizeof(table));   
            hashLinkedNode->next->name = (char *)malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char*));
            strcpy(hashLinkedNode->next->name,str);  
            hashLinkedNode->next->data = val;
            hashLinkedNode->next->next = NULL;
        }
    } 
    fclose(inFile);
    return 0;
}


void printList(BookNode *hd)
{   
    for ( ; hd != NULL; hd = hd->next)
    {
        printf("[%s,%d]", hd->name, hd->isbn);
        if (hd->next)
            printf(" -> ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void printHashTable(BookNode **temp)
{
    BookNode *tmp = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        tmp = temp[i];
        while(tmp)
        {
            printf("%s %d",tmp->name, tmp->isbn);
            tmp=tmp->next;
        }
    }   
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    table **hashLinked[SIZE];
    insert(argv[1],&hashLinked);
    printHashTable(**hashLinked);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you get a seg-fault if you can't even compile your code?

Comment: `table ***hashLinked`??? I've never had to use triple-indirection in any code I've written in 20 years.  Start again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you call `insert` with something other than the type you declared it with,

```
table **hashLinked[SIZE];
insert(argv[1],&hashLinked);
```

`hashLinked` is an array of pointers to pointers to `table`, so `&hashLinked` is a pointer to an array of pointers to pointers to `table`, but `insert` is declared to take a pointer to pointer to pointer to `table`. I'm less than confident that I really figured out what you intended to do, but what seems to be reasonable is that you want fewer levels of indirection. I believe the reason for passing `&hashLinked` is that you want `hashLinked` to be modified in `insert`, but that is already done by passing `hashLinked` itself, you needn't pass its address. That would make the passed type compatible with the declared type, since as a function argument, `hashLinked` becomes a pointer to its first element, a `table ***`.

Then you use inconsistent indirection counts in `insert`, and get the precedence of `*` and `->` wrong, which causes the "request for member in something that isn't a struct or union" errors. `**hashLinked[probe]->name` is parsed `**(hashLinked[probe]->name)`, so tries to access the `name` member of a `table *` and then dereference that twice. With the parameter type `table ***`, the correct access would be `(*hashLinked[probe])->name`, get a `table **` per `hashLinked[probe]`, dereference that once to get a `table *` and access its (pointee)member `name`. However, you check `if (hashLinked[probe] == NULL)`, and if so

```
**hashLinked[probe] = malloc(sizeof(table));
```

which is a guaranteed null pointer dereferencing. By the check and the following code, I believe that you actually want to have a parameter type of `table **`, the `hashLinked` parameter being an array of linked lists of `table`s, which makes the code far easier to follow. Filling in a `BookNode` type and adapting a few variables and parameters, I arrive at

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 5

typedef struct hashTable {
    int data;
    char *name;
    struct hashTable *next;
} table;

typedef struct book {
    int isbn;
    char *name;
    struct book *next;
} BookNode;

int hash_function(int value)
{
    return value % SIZE;
}

int insert(char *inFileName, table **hashLinked)
{
    FILE *inFile;
    int val = -1;
    char str[30];
    int probe;

    if ((inFile = fopen(inFileName, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening input file, %s\n", inFileName);
        return -1;
    }
    while(fscanf(inFile,"%s %d",str,&val) == 2)
    {
        probe = hash_function(val);

        if(hashLinked[probe] == NULL)
        {
            hashLinked[probe] = malloc(sizeof(table));
            hashLinked[probe]->name = (char *)malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char*));
            strcpy(hashLinked[probe]->name,str);

            hashLinked[probe]->data = val;
            hashLinked[probe]->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            table* hashLinkedNode = hashLinked[probe];
            while(hashLinkedNode->next!=NULL)
            {
                hashLinkedNode = hashLinkedNode->next;
            }
            hashLinkedNode->next = malloc(sizeof(table));
            hashLinkedNode->next->name = (char *)malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char*));
            strcpy(hashLinkedNode->next->name,str);
            hashLinkedNode->next->data = val;
            hashLinkedNode->next->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    fclose(inFile);
    return 0;
}

void printList(BookNode *hd)
{
    for ( ; hd != NULL; hd = hd->next)
    {
        printf("[%s,%d]", hd->name, hd->isbn);
        if (hd->next)
            printf(" -> ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void printHashTable(table **temp)
{
    table *tmp = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        tmp = temp[i];
        while(tmp)
        {
            printf("%s %d",tmp->name, tmp->data);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return -1;
    table *hashLinked[SIZE];
    insert(argv[1],hashLinked);
    printHashTable(hashLinked);
    return 0;
}
```

which compiles warning-free and looks like it might do what you intended.